# How to remove unique rows from dataframe using tidyverse

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to remove unique rows based on a variable:

```
Letters  Val
A        1
A        1
B        1
B        3
```

In this case, entries with A is removed as the Val values are unique resulting in:

```
Letters  Val
B        1
B        3
```

I have tried to use count, then filter out `n > 1` however in this process Val is lost.

In essence how do I `filter(count(letters) > 1)`?

Comment: I think what you mean is "I want to remove rows with non-unique/duplicated values"!?

Answer (score 1):

```r
md <- tibble::tribble(
  ~Letters, ~Val,
   "A",        1,
   "A",        1,
   "B",        1,
   "B",        3
  )

library(dplyr)

md |>
  group_by(Letters, Val) |> 
  filter(n() == 1)
#> # A tibble: 2 × 2
#> # Groups:   Letters, Val [2]
#>   Letters   Val
#>   <chr>   <dbl>
#> 1 B           1
#> 2 B           3
```